Nx Version > 18: How to install NX globally on Windows 11 Machine ? what is the difference between npx nx --version and nx --version command?
In windows 11 command prompt, C:\users\EmployeeId

npx nx --version
Local: v18.2.4
Global: Not found 
nx --version
Local: v18.2.4
Global: 16.9.1

npx list -g --depth=0
@nx18.2.4
@angular/cli@17.2.0



How to install Nx globally by latest version?
Thanks
Ramesh

npx install -g nx@latest or npm install -g nx@latest


Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
